# Converting character of YYYYmmdd to date in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a column of characters in YYYYmmdd format to Date class, but I'm getting random integers. Here's the first 5 rows of the dataframe.

```
structure(list(date = c(1947.01000976562, 1947.02001953125, 1947.03002929688, 
1947.0400390625, 1947.05004882812), sp500 = c(15.210000038147, 
15.8000001907349, 15.1599998474121, 14.6000003814697, 14.3400001525879
), divyld = c(4.48999977111816, 4.38000011444092, 4.6100001335144, 
4.75, 5.05000019073486), i3 = c(0.379999995231628, 0.379999995231628, 
0.379999995231628, 0.379999995231628, 0.379999995231628), ip = c(22.3999996185303, 
22.5, 22.6000003814697, 22.5, 22.6000003814697), pcsp = c(NA, 
46.5483322143555, -48.6076202392578, -44.3271369934082, -21.3698806762695
), rsp500 = c(NA, 50.9283332824707, -43.9976196289062, -39.5771369934082, 
-16.319881439209), pcip = c(NA, 5.35716342926025, 5.33335399627686, 
-5.30975437164307, 5.33335399627686), ci3 = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    ci3_1 = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 0), ci3_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0, 0), 
    pcip_1 = c(NA, NA, 5.35716342926025, 5.33335399627686, -5.30975437164307
    ), pcip_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 5.35716342926025, 5.33335399627686
    ), pcip_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.35716342926025), pcsp_1 = c(NA, 
    NA, 46.5483322143555, -48.6076202392578, -44.3271369934082
    ), pcsp_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 46.5483322143555, -48.6076202392578
    ), pcsp_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 46.5483322143555), month = c(-156, 
    -155, -154, -153, -152)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am returned this in the first column:

```
structure(c("-8401", "-8370", "-8342", "-8311", "-8281"), .Dim = c(5L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "date"))
```

```
library("tidyverse")
library("haven")
library("foreign")
library("ggplot2")
library("lmtest")
library("sandwich")
library("forecast")

filepath <- "C:\\Users\\Lui Yu Sen\\Google Drive\\NTU_study materials\\Economics\\HE3021 Intermediate Econometrics\\Week 3\\HE3021-Week-4-Tutorial-3\\rawdata\\VOLAT.dta"
dat <- read_dta(file = filepath)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)
convertdatereadable <- function(datenumeric){
    datenumeric <- trunc(datenumeric * 10000 + 1)
    datenumeric <- as.character(datenumeric)
    return(datenumeric)
}
dat[,1] <- apply(dat[, 1, drop = F], 2, convertdatereadable)
for (n in 1:558){
    dat[n, 1] <- as.Date.character(dat[n, 1], format = "%Y%m%d")
}
```

The dta file has its dates in YYYY.mm in numeric class, so I converted them to YYYYmm01 and truncated them. Then I tried to use as.Date.character. It worked for individual values in the columns, as in, if I called out dat[1,1] it works but not if I use either apply or a for loop. Could someone help me find out what went wrong please? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct however `df$date` is numeric so it has lot more decimal places than you actually see. You could `round` to 2 decimal places and add arbitrary date (`01`) and convert to date class using appropriate format.

```
df$date <- as.Date(paste0(round(df$date, 2), '.01'), '%Y.%m.%d')
df$date
#[1] "1947-01-01" "1947-02-01" "1947-03-01" "1947-04-01" "1947-05-01"
```

Another approach using `zoo::as.yearmon` class.

```
df$date <- as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(as.character(round(df$date,2)), '%Y.%m'))
```

Comment: Yes, I realised a couple of hours in it has more decimal places, that's why I truncated it into YYYYmmdd and then converted it into character class. Thus it worked for individual values but not for the whole column.

Comment: My answer should work for the whole column.

Comment: Yes it did, thank you very much. But if it's possible could I know what went wrong with mine? Many a times I use someone else's code without learning because I don't understand what went wrong with mine.

Comment: On the first glance I could see couple of issues. 1) You should not use loops for functions which are vectorised meaning `as.Date` can work with entire column but you are passing one date at a time to it. 2) A column can hold data of only one type, so you are changing 1st value to date class  however, rest of the value in the column are still numeric so it changes the date back to numeric class. That is also the reason why you should avoid using 1).

Comment: But I tried using apply and it still gave me the same result. I used apply on df[,1, drop = F] down its column.

Comment: `apply` is hidden `for` loop and again wrong tool for such operation.